# Angular js - getting param value via http and serving them to the views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, controller, scope

I'm setting up dinamic config params using $scope:

```
        .controller('AppController', function($scope,$location,$http) {
        $scope.config = {};
        $scope.config.app_ws = "http://localhost/www/";
        $scope.config.app_name = "Appname";
        $scope.config.app_short_description = $scope.config.app_name+" helps you go out with your rabbit";
        $scope.config.app_motto = "hey ohhhhhhhhhh <i class='icon-check'></i>";
        $scope.config.app_url = $location.url();
        $scope.config.app_path = $location.path();
        $http.get($scope.config.app_ws+'jsons/json.json').success(function(response) {
        $scope.config.app_genres =  response;
        });
console.log($scope.config.app_genres); //returns undefined :///
    })
```

but i'm unable to pass to the view `$scope.config.app_genres` (last one)

how do i pass the json as a value ??

if i can't log it out of http() how can i pass it to the view???

the html view is :

```
<div ng-controller="AppController" ng-repeat="i in config.app_genres.genres">
    {{ i }}
</div>
```

json.json is:

```
{
    "genres":["Antani","sturbo"]
}
```

**if i log inside http() it returns in console :**

[image]

**if i log out of http() it returns "undefined"**

Comment: put the console.log inside the $http.get function

Comment: @dcodesmith but how can i make that scope global? i mean i would like to console log out of http :/ , if i can't console log it out of http how can i pass it to the view??

Comment: check proposed solution below

Comment: It could be the the `$http.get` has errors so that your success callback is not triggered. Because when you bind the value to the view, the view will be updated whenever your value changes.

Comment: xhr is ok 304 not modified i can see the json inside :(

Comment: Can we see the structure of the response. is it an array of objects or just an array of numbers/strings?

Comment: if `app_genres` is an array then you can't do `app_genres.genres`.

Comment: @dcodesmith check guys i updated with all i have :P

Comment: try `$scope.config.app_genres =  response.genres`;

Comment: @KhanhTO still undefined if i log it out of http() :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare `$scope.config.app_genres` outside of the `$http.get`, set it inside the `$http.get` and then log it after.

```
.controller('AppController', function($scope,$location,$http) {
    $scope.config = {};
    $scope.config.app_ws = "http://localhost/www/";
    $scope.config.app_name = "Appname";
    $scope.config.app_short_description = $scope.config.app_name+" helps you go out with your rabbit";
    $scope.config.app_motto = "hey ohhhhhhhhhh <i class='icon-check'></i>";
    $scope.config.app_url = $location.url();
    $scope.config.app_path = $location.path();

    $http.get($scope.config.app_ws+'jsons/json.json').success(callback);

    function callback(response) {
        console.log(response); // check this
        $scope.config.app_genres = response[0].genres;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="AppController" ng-repeat="i in config.app_genres">
    {{ i }}
</div>
```

### Solution

The problem here was that `response` was an array of a single object and not an object. So what had to be done was get the first item in the array like so `response[0].genres`

Comment: console.log in this case returns [] :( probably ajax didn't finished yet !? how to get it to block until it's not succeded?

Comment: Ok, how are your using it in your view then? You don't need to log it. Can we see the html. I should've said it won't work coz $http.get is an async function. My bad

Comment: yeah don't worry check i putted html in question

Comment: man it still logging [] and nothing more no data in console :(

Comment: and htis *console.log($scope.config.app_genres.length);* returns 0 in console :(

Comment: check if console.log in callback function returns anything

Comment: Array[1]
0: Object
genres: Array[2]
0: "Antani"
1: "sturbo"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: Are you response is an object and not an array?

Comment: Check the update now, it should work. response is an array, so do response[0].genres.

Comment: yeah it works now man but the problem is the same i can't get the scope out of http or callback

Comment: You don't need to get it out of $http.get(), you can set it in there and it will update it. You can't console.log a variable set in $http.get() but you should be able to use it in your html/view.

Answer (score 1):

try `console.log(response)` to see what the server is returning, sometimes there's more info like headers etc, and the server info is in `response.data`